# databricks catalog root storage change

Tags: databricks, catalog

When creating the catalog in databricks, the storage root and location are set wrong and I would like to change them.But there are already many schemas and tables in this catalog now. How to change the storage root and location without recreating the whole catalog? I didn't find anything anywhere in the docs.[image]

Thanks in advance.